# Assigning char array from ifstream breaks array if adding another char to array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, fstream

So I have an assignment that uses char arrays instead of strings. You assign the array from a .txt file and ifstream. A function I have to write is to concatenate the array with another array. However, the array breaks if I add any extra char after the initial word, even though I initialized the array with plenty of space.

input.txt

```
Hi
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

ifstream in("input.txt");

int main()
{
   char A[50];

   in >> A;
   cout << A << endl;   // expecting to print "Hi"

   A[2] = 't';
   cout << A << endl;   // expecting to print "Hit"

   in.close();
   return 0;
}
```

I expected to see:

```
Hi
Hit
```

Instead it prints:

```
Hi
HitpB
```

Any help?

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explain what C-style strings are, and specifically what special character terminates them. Once you understand how C-style `char` strings work, you should be able to figure out your own problem.

Comment: I already know null terminates the string, I just assumed that indexes 2 - 49 were all null as well. Thank you.

Comment: C++ (and C) has "You don't pay for what you don't use" as a guiding principle (and nulling an array has a cost) so the assumption you should make is "If I don't do it myself, it's not going to happen." But before you make this assumption, check with credible documentation (Text book, man page, Standard document)  to see if you've been thrown a bone for one reason or another.  For example, if `char A[50];` was defined at global scope, the C++ Standard guarantees the whole array would be nulled before you get a chance to use it.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for that advise, that's very insightful!

Comment: Next time I'll make sure to read documentation before asking on StackOverflow, I was trying to find the answer myself but I was googling my specific scenario with no results instead of reading documentation on how arrays are defined in the first place. I see with the amount of negative votes this question got that I should be better at that. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to add '\0' char in zero terminated char array, after you replaced value with index 2.

Comment: Ah I assumed there was already null in all the unused space so when I added the extra char I thought there would still be null in the next space. Thank you